# Computing division of Ed25519 scalars

Tags: source

Is there any implementation that computes `div(x,y) mod l`, where `l` is the order of the base point `G` and `x`,`y` are from that field (i.e. they are ge), or a function that calculates the inverse of a scalar in that field 
(inside the monero code base)?

(I saw that there might exist a function that computes it in the case that`x`,`y` are fe- called `fe_invert` (or maybe `fe_divpowm1`?))

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. Bulletproofs <s>currently use</s> used to use openssl's BN API for this, and now use an optimized algorithm for computing the inverse of a set of scalars.

Comment: Very early Bulletproof code included BN (openssl), but current does not.

Comment: I updated the wording to reflect that change.

Comment: Strictly speaking the Bulletproof function you reference does not perform `div(x,y) mod l` either, which is what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

The division part no. The `mod l` part, yes, `sc_reduce` in [src/crypto/crypto-ops.c](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/b780cf4db1f9dfc49e7f16afc47892a5b40fe68a/src/crypto/crypto-ops.c#L1678).